# XML to JavaScript Array [Google Maps]

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need create Javascript array from xml ..

I`v get xml data from poly php with ajax. Everything is ok.

I must create array like that:

```
  point = [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9921196514,47.8604733650 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9922511293,47.8606186245 ),

        ];
```

Code

```
 downloadUrl("poly.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var polys = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("poly");
        for (var i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {

             var pid  = polys[i].getAttribute("pid");


   point = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(polys[i].getAttribute("plat")), parseFloat(polys[i].getAttribute("plng")) );
        ];
```

i`ve do that but it does not work.. ((

P.S. I get data from MySQL.

...

Xml:

```
    <polys>
<poly pid="1" pstatus="status1" plat="40.992638" plng="47.860474"/>
<poly pid="2" pstatus="status2" plat="40.992252" plng="47.860619"/>
</polys>
```

Comment: please explain "does not work." Are you seeing errors? Strange behavior? What exactly is it doing which is different from what you expect?

Comment: I use     Alert(point); dont show me  anything. But when use             point = [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9921196514,47.8604733650 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9922511293,47.8606186245 ),

        ];   like that it work

Comment: please show us an example- `<poly/>`-element

Comment: ok. I`v edit question. At end added XML poly element

Comment: [Example that parses XML to polylines](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=I5Polyline.xml) (the XML is slighly different format from yours).

Comment: i`m need get only coordinates and one data from this xml. what is wrong in this xml? sorry i dont understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I assume you use the function `downloadUrl` from googles [util.js](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/xmlparsing/util.js?r=16) ?

When yes: `data` is already a document, there is no need to access `data.responseXML`

Each attempt to access a property of `xml` will result in an error, because `xml` is `undefined`

Replace this:

```
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var polys = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("poly");
```

with:

```
    var polys = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("poly");
```

---

There is an syntax-error:

```
point = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(polys[i].getAttribute("plat")), parseFloat(polys[i].getAttribute("plng")) );
        ];
```

remove the semicolon:

```
("plng")) );
//---------^
```

But to get the desired result you must create the point-array outside the loop:

```
var point=[];
```

and add the LatLng's to point inside the loop:

```
point.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(polys[i].getAttribute("plat")),  
                                  parseFloat(polys[i].getAttribute("plng"))));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Bu didnt work :(( .. Myjs page like that http://jsfiddle.net/JFR3n/ ... [i`d include util.js in main page]

Comment: So thanks. I`l do it  with xml point.push  ..it work))   but interesting problem: (40.992638, 47.86047400000007),(40.992252, 47.86061900000004)   it show me this lat long.. but my lat longs like that:  (40.992638  47.860474 ) (40.992252  47.860619)..... what is: 00000007 & 00000004 ? where it take this numbers?:((

Comment: not an solution, but maybe interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307066/why-am-i-not-getting-exact-longitude-when-i-click-on-a-marker/13307262#13307262

Comment: no its solution.. i dont understand ., what is this numbers?:))

Comment: it must be the result of an internal calculation by the maps-API