# Google Maps Coordinates Incorrect

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am i not getting exact Longitude when i click on a marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307066/why-am-i-not-getting-exact-longitude-when-i-click-on-a-marker)

I get data from mysql by xml. Everything is ok. but when i wrote this coordinates with javascript it show me additional numbers.. where it can take this numbers?

like that:

it show me this lat long.. : `(40.992638, 47.860474*00000007*),(40.992252, 47.860619*00000004*)`

but my lat longs like that: `(40.992638 47.860474 ) (40.992252 47.860619)`

what is: **`**00000007 & 00000004 ?**`**

Answer (score 1):

Latitudes and Longitudes are represented in javascript as [double precision floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) (all numbers are).  When you convert a string to a double precision floating point number, it converts it to the closest value, which will not always be exactly the same. The difference in the 14th digit is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanks Guys for help. I solved problem that:

In MySQL may lat long type was float(10,6) I changed it as text. All lat longs coordinates I write again as 12 symbol and it work..

Sorry for my English..