# Longitude is adding extra values

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I want to get street view in my google map infowindow.Iam getting the exact value from database and then passing to google maps LatLng ().But while i am executing the line 
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude); .The value in data[i].Latitude takes some extra values .But i am not able to get where the value comes.
For example data[i].Longitude in database is -73.979000 but after executing the above line it becomes -73.97899999999998.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am i not getting exact Longitude when i click on a marker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307066/why-am-i-not-getting-exact-longitude-when-i-click-on-a-marker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Coordinates Incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183275/google-maps-coordinates-incorrect?lq=1)

Comment: But ehere i need to change my code to get the exact value

Comment: Longitude and Latitude are double precision floating point numbers.  The mantissa is quantized, not all values are possible.  The difference between the two values is too small to matter (calculate it in meters if you are interested).