# Google Maps Javascript API LatLng Class strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API for my little Livetracking-Project. In my work i have encountered a strange behaviour with the LatLng-Class. If i input the two values shown in the example below, i always get this really strange return value from the .lng()-Method from the LatLng-Object, but not so from the .lat()-Method. I was not able to find an explanation for this behaviour in the google documentation. Does anyone else know this issue?

```
var lat = 47.0189;
var lng = 8.33244;
var lastPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
console.log(lastPoint.lat());
console.log(lastPoint.lng());
```

Wich returns:

```
47.0189
8.33244000000002
```

[Screenshot from JS-Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dafus.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the issue? Latitudes and Longitudes are floating point numbers, they sometimes can't exactly represent numbers.

Comment: The problem is that i input 8.33244 and the output is 8.33244000000002.

Comment: Why is that a problem (the difference is not measurable in the real world)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Coordinates Incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183275/google-maps-coordinates-incorrect)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am i not getting exact Longitude when i click on a marker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307066/why-am-i-not-getting-exact-longitude-when-i-click-on-a-marker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JavaScript’s numbers are usually entered as decimal floating-point numbers, but they are internally represented as binary floating-point numbers. That leads to imprecision.

For further details you can read this book:

http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html#number_representation