# Google Map API returns incorrect GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API to allow customers to more accurately identify where their products should be delivered in a city where addresses are inaccurate.

I tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183275/google-maps-coordinates-incorrect) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307066/why-am-i-not-getting-exact-longitude-when-i-click-on-a-marker), but neither resolved the issue.

We place a moveable pin at the location the customer specifies, and then retrieve the GPS coordinates once the customer is satisfied with their placement and hits "continue".

The problem is that the retrieved coordinates are neither the original ones associated with the address nor the new ones associated with the last location of said pin.

```js
  function initMap() {

    var latitude = -8.111735;
    var longitude = -79.025550;

    if(localStorage.getItem('dm-latitude')){
      var latitude = localStorage.getItem('dm-latitude');
      var longitude = localStorage.getItem('dm-longitude');

      if(latitude!='' && longitude!=''){
        $('.dm-clone-btn').addClass('dm-none');
        $('.dm-oroginal-btn').removeClass('dm-none');
      }else{
        $('.dm-clone-btn').removeClass('dm-none');
        $('.dm-oroginal-btn').addClass('dm-none');
      }
    }


    $('#dm-latitude').val(latitude);
    $('#dm-longitude').val(longitude);


    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatLng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var markers = [];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      draggable:true,
      title: latitude+', '+longitude
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    marker.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        title: event.latLng.lat()+', '+event.latLng.lng()
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      localStorage.setItem('dm-latitude',event.latLng.lat());
      localStorage.setItem('dm-longitude',event.latLng.lng());
      $('#dm-latitude').val(event.latLng.lat());
      $('#dm-longitude').val(event.latLng.lng());
      $('.dm-clone-btn').addClass('dm-none');
      $('.dm-oroginal-btn').removeClass('dm-none');

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
      markers.push(marker);
      localStorage.setItem('dm-latitude',event.latLng.lat());
      localStorage.setItem('dm-longitude',event.latLng.lng());
      $('#dm-latitude').val(event.latLng.lat());
      $('#dm-longitude').val(event.latLng.lng());
      $('.dm-clone-btn').addClass('dm-none');
      $('.dm-oroginal-btn').removeClass('dm-none');
    } );


    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      console.log('search ma');
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          title: place.name,
          map: map,
          draggable:true,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));
        console.log(place.geometry);
        localStorage.setItem('dm-latitude',place.geometry.viewport.Za.i);
        localStorage.setItem('dm-longitude',place.geometry.viewport.Ua.i);

        $('#dm-latitude').val(place.geometry.viewport.Za.i);
        $('#dm-longitude').val(place.geometry.viewport.Ua.i);
        $('.dm-clone-btn').addClass('dm-none');
        $('.dm-oroginal-btn').removeClass('dm-none');

        //              console.log(place.geometry.viewport);
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
```

Comment: You are using undocumented properties: `place.geometry.viewport.Za.i` and  `place.geometry.viewport.Ua.i`.  Don't do that (those property names can and do change).  I certainly wouldn't expect any property of the viewport to be related to the actual location of a place (they are likely the north east and south west corners of a bounding box associated with the place.

Comment: Have you heard of Plus codes? [https://plus.codes/] It seems to me that Plus codes could be the solution you are looking for? The Google Maps API also supports Plus codes in most APIs https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-plus-codes-place-autocomplete-place-details-and-geocoding-help-you-serve-users-everywhere

Comment: @geocodezip - That is it! If you put that in an answer, I will accept it. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using undocumented properties: `place.geometry.viewport.Za.i` and `place.geometry.viewport.Ua.i`.

Don't do that (those property names can and do change).

I certainly wouldn't expect any property of the viewport to be related to the actual location of a place (they are likely the north east and south west corners of a bounding box associated with the place.

```
// more details for that place.
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  console.log('search ma');
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

  if (places.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Clear out the old markers.
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  });
  markers = [];

  // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  places.forEach(function(place) {
    if (!place.geometry) {
      console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var icon = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    // Create a marker for each place.
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      title: place.name,
      map: map,
      draggable:true,
      position: place.geometry.location
    }));
    console.log(place.geometry);
    localStorage.setItem('dm-latitude',place.geometry.location.lat());
    localStorage.setItem('dm-longitude',place.geometry.location.lng());

    $('#dm-latitude').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
    $('#dm-longitude').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
    $('.dm-clone-btn').addClass('dm-none');
    $('.dm-oroginal-btn').removeClass('dm-none');

    //              console.log(place.geometry.viewport);
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      // Only geocodes have viewport.
      bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```